# Dúvida sobre funções em linhas Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como as funções trabalham em Javascript, estava olhando em alguns exemplos é não segue a lógica como outras linguagens de programação (PHP e Lua). Eu posso criar uma function na linha 99 e chamar a mesma na linha 1 que aparentemente vai funcionar.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var exemplo = document.getElementByID('exemplo'),
    exemploDois = document.getElementByID('exemplo2');

    init();

    function init(){
        // ... function
    }
```

Isto em outras linguagens geraria um erro retornando um nil value. Em Javascript não precisa seguir a função antes de chamar a mesma? Isto me deixa um pouco confuso ao criar novos códigos em JS.

Em outras linguagens o correto e o seguinte:

```
var exemplo = document.getElementByID('exemplo'),
    exemploDois = document.getElementByID('exemplo2');

    function init(){
        // ... function
    }

    init();
```

O mesmo pode ser feito em variáveis? Pelo que deu a entender o javascript não precisa seguir orientando s funções antes no código.

Comment: está correto das duas formas. Javascript é muito tranquilo.

Comment: Funções declaradas com o `function [name]` vão ao topo do bloco de comandos, se forem declaradas sem o `[name]` elas não vão para o topo do bloco, daí você não pode chamar o `init` antes de declarar ele. Ex: `init(); var init = function() {...};`, então `init` será indefinido e um erro é será jogado no console.